# Making a dynamic formula in Excel using two the FirstRow statement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a line of code to place a formula inside a cell in Excel. I have the formula that works, but I want to make it dynamic, i'm using the FirstRow function to determine the array. The formula is as following:

```
Range("Q" & FirstRow).Offset(1).Formula = "=IF(P43<>P44,1,0)"
```

I've tried placing the FirstRow statement inside the formula:

```
FirstRowOffset1 = Worksheets("WIP extract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
FirstRowOffset2 = Worksheets("WIP extract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(2).Row

Range("Q" & FirstRow).Offset(1).Formula = "=IF(P" & FirstRowOffset1 & ") <> (P" & FirstRowOffset2 & "),1,0"
```

And i've tried using a Set function to place in the formula:

```
FirstRowOffset1 = Worksheets("WIP extract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
FirstRowOffset2 = Worksheets("WIP extract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(2).Row

Set fro1 = Worksheets("Compliance").Range("P" & FirstRowOffset1)
Set fro2 = Worksheets("Compliance").Range("P" & FirstRowOffset2)

Range("Q" & FirstRow).Offset(1).Formula = "=IF( & fro1 &  " <> " &  fro2 & ),1,0"
```

But this only gives a true of false statement inside the cell, not the formula i'm looking for. How can I make the formula dynamic?

```
    LastRowInput = Worksheets("Input").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset().Row
    LastRowMatchC = Worksheets("Compliance").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowSumC = Worksheets("Compliance").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row 'Offset(-1,0)
    FirstRow = Worksheets("WIP extract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row
    FirstRowFill = Worksheets("WIP extract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    FirstRowOffset1 = Worksheets("WIP extract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    FirstRowOffset2 = Worksheets("WIP extract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(2).Row

    '~~> Autofill formules
    Range("P" & FirstRow) = "Check"
    Range("Q" & FirstRow) = "ID"

    Set frCP = Worksheets("Compliance").Range("P" & FirstRowFill & ":P" & LastRowMatchC)

    Range("P" & FirstRow).Offset(1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Input!$A$2:A$" & LastRowInput & ",MATCH(1,SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(Input!$A$2:A$" & LastRowInput & "),O43),0),0),""ZZ"")"
        Range("P" & FirstRow).Offset(1).Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=frCP

    Set frCQ = Worksheets("Compliance").Range("Q" & FirstRowFill & ":Q" & LastRowMatchC)
    Range("Q" & FirstRow).Offset(1).Formula = "=IF(P" & FirstRowOffset1 & " <> (P" & FirstRowOffset2 & ",1,0)"

        Range("Q" & FirstRow).Offset(1).Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=frCQ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplaced this `)`

Change this:

```
Range("Q" & FirstRow).Offset(1).Formula = "=IF(P" & FirstRowOffset1 & ") <> (P" & FirstRowOffset2 & "),1,0"
```

to this:

```
Range("Q" & FirstRow).Offset(1).Formula = "=IF(P" & FirstRowOffset1 & " <> P" & FirstRowOffset2 & ",1,0)"
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: That may be because of some other reason. Can you edit your question and add the entire code you are trying?

Comment: I think you have not initialized the value for FirstRow. You will have to assign some value to FirstRow.

Comment: You have added one extra `(`. Remove `(` from : ` <> (P" & FirstRowOffset2 & ",1,0)"`. Check my answer and use the same code.